# Static version of parse library

Tags: ios, parse-platform, static-linking

Not sure why it is down voted? If the person can provide me a reason, I will try to correct?

---

Does **parse (parse.com)** provide a static version of parse **IOS** library?
We want to statically link parse to our proprietary (static) library and by that way our library users will not be troubled with the requirement of adding the parse SDK libraries etc.
Kindly provide information as whether it is possible to completely hide parse inside our library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com does not provide static libraries.

You can compile a custom static library that includes the parse.com SDK, but **I would not recommend it**. Parse probably does not want you rolling their code into an obfuscated version and would prefer to keep the linking process in place. Parse updates their API and SDK regularly, and your static library would have to be updated to match each time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ryan. I understand downside.  Tried linking the parse framework with our closed static library (where parse calls reside), but it would still required the parse sdk to be included in the app (which includes our closed library). Potentially we want to eliminate this addition in the app side. Could you explain what you mean when you say "compile a custom static library that includes the parse.com SDK". Is it different from what I do?